# iPhone UIWebView becomeFirstResponder

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have an `UIWebView` with an `<input type="text"/>` html element in it.
I want to focus the input element in the html and show the keyboard on the iPhone programmatically, without tapping the screen.

I've tried the following:

- set the focus from JavaScript (in this case the onFocus JS event will fire but the keyboard won't show up)
- `[webView becomeFirstresponder]` (returns NO)
- set the first subview of the webView to be the `firstResponder` (returns NO)
- subclass `UIWebView` to return YES to `canBecomeFirstResponder`: (nothing happens)

I'm trying to find the solution since yesterday but I couldn't find it.
Please help.

Comment: I don't know how you managed to create this problem but normally the becomeFirstResponder has to be used like I described it in my article: http://bcaccinolo.wordpress.com/2010/12/28/uitextfield-with-the-keyboard-automagically/

Comment: -1, It doesn't work for UIWebView.

Comment: did you found some solution for this? The only way I found is to programmatically emulate a click on the WebView. But my app may be rejected because of this... :(

Comment: Starting with iOS 6 you can use [keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do this.

Comment: Have you tried to put the focus method to the onload action of the web page?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474386/uiwebview-with-contenteditable-html-editing-first-responder-handling

Comment: Try out this answer. It may help you.

[UIWebView with contentEditable (html editing), first responder handling?][1]

Thanks
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474386/uiwebview-with-contenteditable-html-editing-first-responder-handling

Answer (score 2):

In iOS6 or above, you have to set `keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction` to `NO` first:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    webView.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = NO;
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"theElementId\").setFocus();"]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? Don't forget to wire up the UIWebView's delegate connection, and ideally execute the javascript only when required.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"theElementId\").setFocus();"]; 
}
```