# UIWebView with contentEditable (html editing), first responder handling?

Tags: html, uiwebview, contenteditable, html-editor, first-responder

I'm making an html editor component for an app (using UIWebView with contentEditable in iOS 5.0), and got stuck at how to handle UIWebView first responder status

[webView isFirstResponder], [webView becomeFirstResponder] and [webView resignFirstResponder] don't seem to work, and i've no idea how to make the webView become or resign it by code

If anyone knows how to work this out i would be very grateful, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13):

Here is how I overwrite these methods in a `UIWebView` subclass (`content` is the id of the editable element):

```
-(BOOL)resignFirstResponder {
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];[self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    return [super resignFirstResponder];
}

// only works on iOS 6+
-(void)becomeFirstResponder {
    self.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = NO; // set here or during initialization  
    // important note: in some situations (newer iOS versions), it is also required to first call `blur()` on the 'content' element, otherwise the keyboard won't show up as expected
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('content').focus()"];
}

-(BOOL)isFirstResponder{
    if ([[self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.activeElement.id=='content'"] isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

`isFirstResponder` will only return true after the keyboard is shown (e.g, it will return false at UIKeyboardWillShowNotification)

In case this is an issue, another way to check if the `UIWebView` is the first responder is as follows:

```
+(BOOL)isFirstResponder:(UIView *)v{
    for (UIView *vs in v.subviews) {
        if ([vs isFirstResponder] || [self isFirstResponder:vs]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
-(BOOL)isFirstResponder{
    return [[self class] isFirstResponder:self];
}
```

This way, the returned value will be `YES` even before/after the keyboard animation finishes (showing or hiding).

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem recently, but solved it using pure JavaScript. Actually it doesn't need any Objective-C First Responder related methods. I just used the JavaScript to change the UIWebView's content - the targeting HTML element's contentEditable attribute value according to the requirement.

For example, using the following code to hide the Keyboard that called by the UIWebView's editable content:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('target').setAttribute('contentEditable','false')"];
```

Hope this is helpful. :)

Comment: thanks a lot! however, i also need use of the "becomeFirstResponder" and "isFirstResponder" equivalent methods for other purposes

Comment: i got stuck with other things in my work and couldn't fully test this, but now i did, and it doesn't seem to work, iPhone or iPad ... do you do anything else that could affect the keyboard??

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I overwrite these methods in a UIWebView subclass (content is the id of the editable element):

```
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('content').focus()"];
```

But Focus go to 1st point not last point

Answer (score -2):

Call the following lines of code when you want to hide the keyboard.

```
//wView is your UIWebView

NSString *webText = [wView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
 [wView loadHTMLString:webText baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score -2):

[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", htmlString] baseURL:nil];
This works in iOS > 4