# Focus contenteditable div in UIWebView programmatically

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios5, uiwebview, contenteditable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show keyboard in contenteditable UIWebView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835956/show-keyboard-in-contenteditable-uiwebview-programmatically)

I want to make something like a WYSIWYG-Editor on the iPhone (iOS5). After searching the web I found a great [tutorial](http://ios-blog.co.uk/articles/tutorials/rich-text-editing-a-simple-start-part-1/) which uses a UIWebView with a contenteditable div. It works as expected and I'm really pleased with the result.

But there's one thing that doesn't work. I can't focus the contenteditable div via JavaScript (stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:). I've tried everything I know... focus (w/ and w/o jQuery), I've tried to simulate a click (also w/ and w/o jQuery), ...

I'd like the keyboard to show up as soon as the view is presented.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible: the browser requires a genuine user interaction to allow focus.