# contenteditable div in UiWebView - new lines are not saved when clicking on done

Tags: html, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, ios6

I have the following div in `UIWebView`:

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

If the user inserts new line (using the return key in the visual keyboard), and when he is done he clicks on done in the previous/next/done grey visual keyboard, it combines the lines to one line.

How can I avoid it?

[image: While editing]
[image: After clicking done]

Comment: put some code for more understanding :) thanks :)

Comment: If u add to the html in the input tag onkeyboadDown(callfunction()) this function would check the value entered so far so u can detect if the value is a return or any other character, if it was a return add /n to the value. I haven't tried this option, but its worth trying.

Comment: Are you applying any styles to plain `<div>` elements (e.g. `display: inline`)? The HTML generated in your example would be `San<div>Francisco</div>`.

Comment: please reply to the above question?

Comment: No I don't apply styles to the plain element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps **[this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yZZk/4/)** can shed some light onto what's happening within your application. If you type some lines in the top DIV (gray background color), the HTML code that you get as the return value of its `innerHTML` property will first display in a `textarea` field below it (including HTML tags formatting). As you will soon see it's not merely what you'd expect to handle in your application ('line one' + CRLF + 'line two'...), but it also contains HTML elements separating lines one from another. That's how browsers are able to display `contenteditable` DIVs as if they're 'memo' type controls - by parsing their HTML (that's what browsers do). This HTML formatted text is also how your application receives user submitted text, and there you have to decide what to do with this formatting. You can either strip them away (which is, I suspect, how you set that object's property and it deals with that for you) replacing HTML elements like `<DIV></DIV>` and so on with a space character, or choose (with your control's property, or in code) to handle this formatting whichever way you'd like them to be handled. I'm not familiar with `UIWebView` though, and you'll have to find on your own how to retrieve complete HTML formatted values that you want to apply to the next DIV element that you're displaying (or same one that you're assigning new values to).

UPDATE: After searching the web for `UIWebView` reference, I've actually stumbled across [one related thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474386/uiwebview-with-contenteditable-html-editing-first-responder-handling) that shows how to retrieve innerHTML value of an element in your underlying HTML document:

```
//where 'wView' is your UIWebView

NSString *webText = [wView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('inputDIV').innerHTML"];
```

This way you'd be able to retrieve the whole `innerHTML` string contained within the `contenteditable` DIV that you use in a `webText` string variable and parse its HTML formatted text to whatever suits your needs better. Note though, that different browsers format `contenteditable` DIVs differently when `Enter Key` is pressed and some will return the next line enclosed in a new `DIV`, while others might enclose it in paragraph `P` and/or end the line with a break `<BR>` or `<BR />`, when `shift`+`enter` were used together to move to the next line. You will have to account for all these possibilities when processing your input string. Refer to the [JSFiddle script I wrote](http://jsfiddle.net/9yZZk/4/) using your `UIWebView` component to check what formatting applies.

Of course, in your case, it might be simpler to replace your `contenteditable` DIV with a `textarea` that will return more commonly formatted `\n` end-of-line (CR+LF). DIVs however are easier to design, so choose whichever suits your needs better.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a solution to this from the objective-c side of the stack. The standard HTML- element only delivers a single string. It might be possible to achieve through some javascript magic or similar on the web-end of things.

My HTML-skills are not up to scratch but if you also control that end perhaps changing the  to a textArea might help?