# How to show keyboard forcefully for uiwebview

Tags: uiwebview

I have created Rich Text Editor using UIWebView . I want to show keyboard without tapping uiwebview , means when i open editor keyboard should be open and uiwebview should be editable.

Comment: Refer to [THIS][1] post on stackoverflow


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287478/mobile-safari-autofocus-text-field

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIWebView with contentEditable (html editing), first responder handling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474386/uiwebview-with-contenteditable-html-editing-first-responder-handling)

Answer (score 0):

Just write this delegate method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    webView.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = NO;
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('content').focus()"];
```

}

content is the element's id.

Comment: This puts it in focus, but does not bring up the keyboard.